# How do I send data with USB and read with driver?

Tags: c, char, hex, decimal, ascii

Via my usb connection I receive some commands, which I would like to make them readable for my driver.

First char is a letter S and afterwards a few numbers (4) come inside.
I want to transform this numbers from asci to decimal and then write them as HEX in other function. Maximum size can be 20 bits.

Since I am new with C I have problems with this transforming.

I would be glad if someone could give me some advices.

```
u8 x;
u8 xx;
u8 xxx;
u8 xxxx;
u32 y;

void ProcessCommandUSB(u8 b_Data[USB_COMMAND_LENGTH],u8 b_DataLength) 
{ 
    switch (b_Data[0])  // process first byte
    {
    case '\r':  // ignore
        break;

    case '\n':  // ignore
        break;

    ////// SPEED ///////
    case 'S':
        x= b_Data[1];
        xx= b_Data[2];
        xxx= b_Data[3];
        xxxx= b_Data[4];

// I NEED TO CHECK IF VARIABLES ARE NUUMBERS, OTHERWISE ERROR.
if (x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='0')|(x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='1')|(x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='2')\
  |(x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='3')|(x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='4')|(x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='5')\
|(x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='6')|(x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='7')|(x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='8')|(x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='9');
{
        //to make asci char, decimal
        x = (x-48)* 1000; 
        xx = (xx-48)* 100;
        xxx =(xxx-48)* 10;
        xxxx -= 48;
    y=x+xx+xxx+xxxx;  
}
    //THIS PART OF CODE DOWN WORKS, AND I WANT TO WRITE THE BYTES RECEIVED 
    //WITH S COMMAND (Y), IN FUNCTION RUN INSTEAD OF 0x034444. 

    else
{
    sprintf(vrni, "D Error\r");
}

USB_Send_String (vrni);
    break;

    case 'D':  // version

        if(b_Data[1] == '<')
        {
            RUN(REV, 0x034444);
            sprintf(vrni, "nazaj\r");

             ....... //REST OF THE CODE WORKS
```

Comment: Did you mean `xx = (xx-48)* 100;` and `xxx =(xxx-48)* 10;`? I can't see the point of your `(x-48)` in those two lines.

Comment: Yes!
Sorry for mistake.

Comment: Do you mean sorry for the coding error, or for posting code that is not your code?

Comment: "I NEED TO MERGE X VARIABLES IN HEX FORMAT" - just add them `x + xx + xxx + xxxx`. I presume the input is in decimal as you multiply digits by `10` etc. There is no such thing as "hex format", numbers are stored in binary. If you want to output the number in the human readable hex format you can use the `printf` family with format specifier, for example `%05X`.

Comment: BTW you need a `break;` at the end of `case S:` code block unless you intend the execution to fall through to the next `case`.

Comment: I added to code things that you suggested but code is still wrong. I dont know how to write the if condition right already...

Comment: Please don't give progress reports by changing the code you posted - if necessary add an update. The edit's `x,xx,xxx,xxxx =='0'` does not compare each of those values with `'0'`. That line is not valid syntax anyway, the parenthising is incorrect, and the trailing `;` makes it do nothing.

Comment: Could you help me how to solve this issue. I will post update next time, i didnt know it since im new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example shows one way to convert the four decimal bytes to a number and then output as hexadecimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char message[24];
    char b_Data[] = "S9876";
    unsigned num;
    if(b_Data[0] == 'S') {
        if(isdigit(b_Data[1]) && isdigit(b_Data[2]) && 
                                 isdigit(b_Data[3]) && isdigit(b_Data[4])) {
            num = (b_Data[1] - '0') * 1000 + 
                  (b_Data[2] - '0') * 100 + 
                  (b_Data[3] - '0') * 10 + 
                   b_Data[4] - '0';             // use '0' not magic number
            sprintf(message, "%05X", num);
            printf ("%s\n", message);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
02694
```

BTW, your `x` variable as 8-bit was not large enough to hold the value you assigned to it.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your kindness and help but I dont get it how the output becomes 02694?

And if I understand now correctly I just need to write unsigned num instead of 0x034444 (in function RUN in case R)

Comment: The decimal input `9876` is hexadecimal `02694`, which was created with the `%05X` format specifier.

Comment: Thank you, its much more clear to me now, how to contiue my project!

Comment: I am still struggling how to use this hex nmb that i get now in next function RUN, instead of 0x034444. I want that the speed can be changed when i want.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to, better to ask a new question showing exactly what the current problem is.

Comment: I want to use variable NUM, that i get with this function, in next case D in function RUN(REV, NUM). It is posted in my code above.
 I edited your part of code because i need different format (for example 0x034444)
sprintf(vrni, "0X%06X", num);